# Single word for "able to be expensed"

Tags: word-request

Is there a single word for "able to be expensed"? *Expensable* and *expensible* do not appear to be in any dictionary I've seen, but I'd *swear* I've seen them used.

Comment: The word _claimable_ might work.

Answer (score 8):

In US English, I've seen the term *reimbursable* used for a business expense for which your employer will repay you at a later date.

Comment: It's already implied in this answer, but I'd like to note explicitly that _reimbursable_ refers to a wholly contained subset of expensable items. There may be a one-to-one correlation depending on the workplace (i.e. everything expensable is reimbursable), but there are useful distinctions between the two words in terms of specificity and implied outcome.

Answer (score 4):

“Expensable” is the right word. Here it is in eHow’s definition of expense reports:

> Meals and entertainment are often **expensable** costs
> <sub>Source: [eHow, *What Is the Definition of an Expense Report?*](http://www.ehow.com/facts_5911529_definition-expense-report_.html)</sub>

Here it is in a Wikipedia article on Capital expenditure:

> Most ordinary business expenses are clearly either **expensable** or capitalizable
> <sub>Source: [Wikipedia, *Capital expenditure*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capital_expenditure)</sub>

It’s formed by adding the highly productive suffix “-able” (meaning *fit for)* to the verb “expense”.

> **-able**
>
> 1. a suffix meaning “capable of, susceptible of, **fit for**, tending to, given to,” associated in meaning with the word able, occurring in loanwords from Latin (*laudable*); **used in English as a highly productive suffix to form adjectives by addition to stems of any origin** (*teachable; photographable*).
>
> <sub>Source: [dictionary.com definition of *-able*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/-able)</sub>

I hear this word used all the time in my office (in Chicago). Dictionaries don’t always list every adjective that gets formed like this.

Answer (score -1):

How about *consumable* or simply *usable*?

Are you sure what you saw was not *expansible*? Which looks very alike, but means "able to be expanded."